# $_COOKIE[] not working

Tags: php

I just switched over from a wamp server to actually just installing apache, php, and mysql and setting them up manually.  I'm find that when I call $_COOKIE it throws an undefined index message.  The cookie is valid and exists but it won't recognize the cookie.

Cookie is set on sign in script

```
< ?php 

if (username/password to match dataserecord)
{
setcookie('error', 'invalid login');  //cookie gets set
header('Location: signin.php');  //page is redirected correctly
?>
```

Here is the echo call to display the cookie/error on the sign in page

```
< ?php echo $_COOKIE['error'] ?>  //undefined index
```

Would I need to adjust a setting in php or apache?

Comment: Don't use cookies for that. Use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Have you checked that the cookie gets sent to the browser? Have you checked the cookie gets sent back to PHP? Did you dump the whole `$_COOKIE` array to see which cookies are actually detected?

Comment: are you using cookies for your login if it was valid too? Also, make sure you use `die()` or `exit()` after the `header()`!

Comment: +1 for the use of [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).  But it's worth pointing out that `setcookie()` also returns a boolean indicating whether it was sent (unfortunately not whether it was accepted) -- you should ensure it returns true.  If it does not, you've already sent output and are now trying to send headers -- this won't work.

Comment: I did a var_dump($_COOKIE) and am not seeing the cookie.  Any reason why it would physically be there but php not seeing the cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i totally agree with what Kolink said about using sessions for this purpose, but if you insist on going the cookie route, i believe the cookie isnt being read due to no set cookie path, eg

```
setcookie('error', 'invalid login', '/');  //cookie gets set
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and it worked.  I wasn't sure if using cookies for the error messages would reduce the load on the server.

Comment: dont think there is too much difference in that respect, only real difference being life span. a session will end when the browser is closed but a cookie can have a defined expiry time. your cookie above will expire when the browser is closed due to the fact there is no expiry parameter passed, which is ok for this cookies purpose. but for example, a remember me cookie for a login script, will need an extended life span eg. `setcookie('remember_me', 'login_detail_here', '/', time()+86400);` which will expire in 24hrs